# Cannot $compile template with same class as directive even though directive is declared as restrict "E"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say I have a directive "foo":

```
app.directive("foo", function($compile) {
    var innerTemplate = $compile('<div class="foo"></div>');
    return {
        restrict: "E";
    };
}));
```

Why is it that the $compile call will fail, complaining that fooDirective depends on fooDirective, even though the directive is declared to be restricted to "E"?

Edit: Added example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n4bvkbp7/1/

Answer (score 1):

The directive "foo" must be fully defined before you can compile it.  Try putting your compile statement in your directives link function:

```
app.directive("foo", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function() {
              var linkFn = $compile('<div class="foo"></div>');
         }
    };
}));
```

Comment: it works given syntax for `function(){}`  is corrected

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `link: function() { // }`. I tried that and it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need a $compile service here:

```
    ngModule.directive('foo', ['$compile', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div class="foo">foo</div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){

              //TODO:
            }

        }

}]);
```

Comment: agree , nothing special about template that it should need to manually call `$compile`. Should be able to remove as dependency also

Comment: I know that I can use `template` if I only want to link the template once. However, assuming (for hypothetical reasons, if only for the sake of the existence of such a use case) that I want to link my template with two different scopes, the second scope possibly based on the scope passed in, eg:
    `link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.append(template(scope));
        element.append(template(scope.$new()); // maybe a cloned scope of the current scope with certain values changed.
    }`

Comment: @markwongsk that doesn't really make a lot of sense. You would use isolated scope if that's what you needed

Answer (score 0):

You were using `$compile` function outside of return statement, that means that will execute in its compile time, you can compile your element `postLink` function only.

**Directive**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.directive("foo", function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var innerTemplate = $compile('<div class="foo">HELLO WORLD</div>');
            element.append(innerTemplate(scope));
            //do other logic here
        }
    };
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/n4bvkbp7/2/)